# Login Braintree with Paypal

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, braintree, paypal-subscriptions, payment-processing

I already have a PayPal business account. Do I need a seperate Braintree business account for Braintree integration or can I use PayPal business account itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of Braintree integration? For PayPal Checkout via a Braintree SDK you can get credentials at the bottom of: https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications .  There's some information about this specific integration [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/braintree-integration/), although most of what you need will be on the Braintree site.

If you want *other* Braintree gateway features, you need to apply for a Braintree account for your business. It'll be connected to your PayPal account.

Comment: Yea that's my doubt should I need a Braintree account even if I have a PayPal business account and also is the pricing will be different?

Comment: Well that's what my answer addressed. It depends on what you want to do with Braintree. The pricing will likely be standard.